# MVC View is returning null model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I don't know why its not working there is nothing complicated. I am just passing model to view and then getting the model back from view for updating.

**Controller :**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Test")]
    public ActionResult Test_get()
    {
        Testing t = new Testing();
        t.a = 100;
        t.name = "ali";
        t.age = "29";
        return View(t);
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public class Testing
{
    public int a = 0;
    public string name;
    public string age;
}
```

**View:**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     @Html.Label("name")
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.name)
     @Html.Label("age")
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.age)    
    <button type="submit" value="Change Text" />
}
```

and this method get model back

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Test")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Test_post(Testing t)
    {
        Testing get_t = new Models.Testing();
        get_t = t;
        return View();
    }
```

but it returns null model please help me this is just demo I am stuck in my project.

Comment: Your class `Testing` contains only fields. Make them properties i.e `public int a { get; set; }` so the `DefaultModelBinder` can **set** them.

Comment: Oh what a small mistake.. thank you soooo much you make my day :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your mode to use properties, then only MVC *model binding*  will work

```
public class Testing
{
    public int a = 0;
    public string name { get; set;} 
    public string age { get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: thank you.. i was struggling for 2 days for this :-)